Can an Excel VB textbox be unlocked so the user can drag it around freely in a protected worksheet?
I'm writing a scheduling app in Excel for a testing center and the idea I had was to create textbox objects (VB objects, not Excel objects) of different heights that represent tests of different time limits. There are 8 workstations so my theory was that I set up the spreadsheet rows to reflect the hours the testing center is open, each row representing 15 minutes. The user can then drag a textbox over a workstation column and drop it over the right start time in that column, then fill in the text box with the testing student's details.
I can't seem to find a property that will keep all the textboxes I need to create constantly draggable. I've got them set to unlocked, but that doesn't seem to matter. In fact, once design mode is turned off, the textbox is immovable even without the sheet being protected (duh, right, that's the way it should be).
I know I can probably do this with dynamic images, but that seems like an extra step and code that I wouldn't have to do if the textboxes were just draggable by the users. Any ideas?

to be clear: you want a draggable-interactivity between a VBA form and a worksheet?

Why not fill in a student's detail directly in a cell?

Because the textbox can be different size heights, representing the time limit of the test. Just putting the information in cell means that that all cells in that row are the same height and that row just expands. All the textboxes will be different heights for 1hr, 1.5, 2hr, tests, etc. This means you can drag a textbox over the timeslot and have it automatically cover up the time it will takeup for that workstation.

@Yorik No, just a plain worksheet with texboxes that can move over columns. No VBA forms.

While it may be possible to use Excel for this, it is stretching that product into something it really wasn't designed for, and there are already scheduling tools and systems, including built in to Outlook (Calendars, for instance) that already handle scheduling and are DESIGNED for scheduling. I strongly recommend that you look to alternate ways for handling this. Just because you like your hammer does not mean every problem you face is a nail.
